# Where to start when creating a PhoneGap based app?

Tags: cordova

I am looking to create a basic smart phone app for all major smart phones operating systems (this includes: iOS, Android, Windows, and Blackberry). But I have no clue as to where to start. The app I am looking to create would be very basic. It would display some content that would change on a daily basis. It would alert the user when new content is in and the user can view the content. The user would also be able to see past content.

While the app itself would be fairly simple I do not know where to start. I run windows software and do not have a mac. (Preventing me from building iOS correct?) Also my knowledge of coding for apps is none. I know HTML/CSS/ and some javascript. I have thought of using PhoneGap to do what I need and using PhoneGap's built in integration in Dreamweaver CS6 (Using PhoneGap will allow me to creat for iOS correct?). I need to be able to do this without having to learn new code (or at least a lot of new code, basics I can handle, I am still learning javascript!).

So my question is where is it best I start to attempt to learn how to create a PhoneGap based app that will do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html

You'll need a Mac and iOS developer certification to make an iOS app, even on PG/Cordova. But you'll be able to develop for other platforms on your Windows machine.

My experience with PG/Cordova is great on Android, ok on iOS, and blurgh on Blackberry (both phone and tablet). But I blame it mostly on Blackberry for this love, love as I do my phone and Playbook.

You will *have* to learn more to make a Phonegap app, especially if you want to load external content onto the phone (look up jQuery, and especially the jQuery.ajax() method), and prettify the User Interface (jQuery Mobile *et altri*).

However, frameworks like Phonegap (there are others, but so far PG's my favorite) are the easiest solution for beginners (and advanced) coders to make a quick, simple mobile app.

So, read the PG/Cordova docs, search stackoverflow for questions that have been asked and answered already on this subject (use the phonegap tag), and work on your JS skills!

Comment: Thanks for the info, and I do not mind learning more it is having to learn a new scripting/programming language from scratch is not what I want to do => I do want to learn more on JS though. I thought I had read that with the DW integration it would eliminate the need to have a mac to build for iOS. Maybe I read wrong. =>

Comment: To build iOS apps with PG (like with any other framework), you need XCode, the iOS simulator or a device (which needs to be provisioned in XCode), and an Apple Developer account + iOS dev certification. I suppose you can develop the HTML/JS part of a PG app in Dreamweaver, but when it comes to compiling, there's no other way...

Comment: Ah! I found the comment I was referring to from the PhoneGap website `Yes DW6 does  allow you to build for IOS on Windows as we do all the compilation in the cloud!` - and - `It is actually possible. However you will need to use the OS X platform to create an Apple Developer iOS account and generate a key to sign your app. With DW CS6, the apps do not get compiled on your machine. The PhoneGap Build Service does it all. I just did it. :)` - http://phonegap.com/2012/04/24/adobe-dreamweaver-cs6-supports-phonegap-build/ - Look in the comment section at the last few comments.